# Center align rotated element contained within parent element

Tags: html, css

I have an element using `transform: rotate(90deg);` but it is not centered in the parent element.

I am also trying to make this as cross-browser as possible (transparency, etc) but so far haven't had the best of luck.

**jsFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/K8RXr/4**

*Reason I am rotating `&lt;` is because I will be using an icon font/image to replace this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't appear to be centering is because you have rotated it. When css goes off of transformations, it does all of the normal styling, then transforms it. So if you were to remove the `transform`, you would see that the problem doesn't lie with the horizontal centering, it is the vertical centering that is the problem. To solve this, you must add

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

for the arrow to align in the middle

I have the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/K8RXr/6/)

Also, if you ever need help with making something more cross-browser compatible, http://prefixr.com/ is a great tool for doing this. For example, it would turn your `opacity:0.5;` into

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity:0.5;
```

Which should help for Internet Explorer

Comment: You answered so fast I couldn't accept it until 10 minutes later.

Comment: Did this help you? I also edited my answer to include the cross compatibility issue